# How to store an array of strings in a file using C (one string per line)?

Tags: c, file-handling

I want to store some strings in a text file (one string per line), but on compilation, some unnecessary zeroes get added at the end of each string in the text file.
Following is my code :-
**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

    int main()
    {
        int i=0;
        char *name[4]={"ABC","agb","thi","yuun"};
        FILE *pp;
        pp=fopen("random_name.txt","w");
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            fwrite(name[i],strlen(name[i])+1,1,pp);
            fputs("\n",pp);
        }
        fclose(pp);
        return 0;
    }
```

**
[Here's the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcxgu.png)

Comment: Why this: ' strlen(name[i])+1' ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **+1** from `strlen(name[i])+1` and update your `fwrite()` function:

> `fwrite(name[i],strlen(name[i]),1,pp);`

Answer (score 0):

> unnecessary zeroes get added at the end of each string in the text
> file.

**Reason**: Each of `name[i]` string ends with `\0` (ASCII 0). You are giving, `strlen(name[i])+1` as the argument to `fwrite`. So, the null terminating character (`\0`) will also be written to the file.

**Solution** : To avoid it, change `fwrite(name[i],strlen(name[i])+1,1,pp);`  to `fwrite(name[i],strlen(name[i]),1,pp);`